# inequality question in x and y

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, factoring

1. Let $a,b\ge2$ Show that we have $a+b\le ab$. For this i just showed
   that the inequality $x+y\le xy$ has some of its solutions in the
   range $x,y\ge 2$ (i factorised $xy-x-y+1$) is this a valid way to
   show this?
2. What does it mean to find an example when equality holds given an
   inequality in $x$ and $y$, and when it does not hold. for example,
   does equality refer to when the inequality is true or speicifially
   when both sides are equal?

Thanks

Comment: Note that $a,b \ge 2 \implies a+b \ge 4$, please check your question.

Comment: "Equality" refers specifically to the two sides being equal.  If $x+ y\le 2$ then x= 1, y= 1 satisfy x+ y= 2 so satisfy that inequality.  If x= 1/2 and y= 1/2 then x+ y= 1< 2 so satisfy that inequality.

Comment: would the second case be an example  of a solution which does not satisfy equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$ab-a-b=(a-1)(b-1)-1\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $a-1=b-1=1$, id est, for $a=b=2.$

Comment: Thanks so is it just a case of making it clearer that its true on that domain of a and b?

Comment: @James Anthony Yes, it's true for $a\geq2$ and $b\geq2$.